# How to bridge requests from one service to another in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm developing a service in ASP.NET Core Web API which acts as a proxy for another service. For few specific endpoints it should handle the requests itself, but for all others endpoints I want it to act as a bridge to the other service, sending the request as-is, and also returning its responses as is.

I kind of managed to do that, but it becomes pretty complex and I keep finding edge cases that need special treatment, even though I believed it should be a pretty straightforward problem. So I wonder if I'm missing a simpler solution.

Here's the gist of what I tried to do:

- I created an endpoint with `[Route("{**all}")]` to handle all routes that are not handled by other endpoints.
- In that method I created a [`HttpRequestMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-8.0) object based on the values in [`ControllerBase.Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.request?view=aspnetcore-8.0), including the Method, route, query-string, headers and body, and sent it to the other server using [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0)
- With the [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-8.0) object I got from from [`HttpClient.SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-8.0) I populated the values in [`ControllerBase.Response`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.response?view=aspnetcore-7.0), including the status code, headers and body.

Some issues that I encountered (the first 2 I resolved, the last one I haven't tried yet, as I figured that it's getting too complicated)

- [`ResponsePhrase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.reasonphrase?view=net-8.0) wasn't bridged
- When sending a request from a browser, I got error 404 and had to remove the original [Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header in order to solve that
- If response body is not very small, (e.g. Swagger HTML) it was not bridged correctly due to chunking error.

So am I missing some simpler solution? If it's really complex, isn't there any existing method or library that already does it?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I used https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy before, with a Backend-for-frontend solution. Some of the requests were handled by the BFF and some were forwarded as they are to an internal API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that YARP is something that you are looking for :

https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/api/index.html

It has everything you need (and more) - we managed to put swagger, even hangfire dashboard through it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it looks promising, but I didn't manage to get it working. I looked on their Getting Started guide, but my project is initialized using a `WebHost` and `UseStartup`, and I couldn't find where to apply the line `app.MapReverseProxy();`. Can you advise on that?

Comment: I managed to do that! this example helped me: https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/blob/release/1.1/samples/ReverseProxy.Transforms.Sample/Startup.cs